# cakephp remove controller name from url

Tags: cakephp, routes, cakephp-2.0, cakephp-2.1

i am working on a cakephp 2.x .. right now i have a function called forgetpassword and resetpassword in my userscontroller .. i am sending an email to a user..

i am sending a url like this ..this code is written in the forgetpassword function

```
 $url = Router::url( array('controller'=>'users','action'=>'resetpassword'), true   ).'/'.$key.'#'.$hash;
```

and i receive this url in my inbox like this

https://www.myweb.com/resetpassword/y2273727372jhgdfjjd2434dff#23232323

when i click the url which is on my inbox .. it is giving me an error .. not going to the resetpassword function .. instead if i add the controller name behind the function then it successfully loading the page

e.g

```
 https://www.myweb.com/users/resetpassword/y2273727372jhgdfjjd2434dff#23232323
```

but i dont want the controller name behind the function in the url

routes.php

```
   Router::connect('/resetpassword', array('controller' => 'users', 'action'=>'resetpassword'));
```

Comment: You don't need the # part. PHP cannot use it anyway. Passed params are attached differently, thus your connect() rule is not correct, either. Try `Router::connect('/resetpassword/*', ...)`

Comment: so what is the correct syntax for connect... i always use use this and it works .. but this time i am stuck in quite different situation .. but whenever i want to remove the controller name i do this

Comment: @mark you should answer the question. This way helloshelkh can accept it and you guys get more rep.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Router::connect('/resetpassword', ...)
```

means, that you are not using anything after it as passed params etc.
But you do that, so correct is:

```
Router::connect('/resetpassword/*', ...)
```

Also note that

```
Router::url( array('controller'=>'users','action'=>'resetpassword'), true   ).'/'.$key.'#'.$hash;
```

is wrong, it should be - as documented:

```
Router::url(
    array(
        'controller' => 'users', 
        'action' => 'resetpassword',
        $key, // passed param
        '#' => $hash // hash
    ), true);
```