# Set wildcard Router cakephp

Tags: php, .htaccess, cakephp, wildcard, router

Ahoy...
I want create rule, when I access for profile page on mysite:

Expectation:
http://www.example.net/johnsnow

I've created route like this

```
Router::connect('/*', array('controller' => 'users',  'action' => 'profile'));
```

It's work for (http://www.example.net/johnsnow) But then the default cake Router and Router definition after that didn't works, also I've tried this Route.

```
Router::connect('/:name', array('controller' => 'users',  'action' => 'profile'), array('pass' => array('name')));
```

the result is same :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In cakephp if you want to remove controller name from URL , just add below line on your's routes.php file.

**Router::connect('/:action', array('controller' => 'pages'));**

its come something like that locahost/stiename/action

> Please refer below links :
>
> http://anuragtrivediphp.blogspot.in/2011/09/remove-controller-name-from-url.html
>
> [cakephp remove controller name from url](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18214271/cakephp-remove-controller-name-from-url)

Comment: I am very glad, I could help you ... @rslhdyt